# Segue from Custom Cell (dynamic Prototype Cell)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios7, storyboard, segue

Im using the Storyboard to create my UI.
I have a SplitViewController. The MasterViewController holds a TableViewController where I created a CustomCell with Custom Design.

The Cells are shown pretty good with my data.
The point is: The Custom Cell also holds an Info-Button, with should Popup a little 300x88 TableViewController with some data.

If the Cells in my MasterViewController->TableViewController where a Static one, I just would drag & drop a Segue from the Info-Button to my Popup-TableViewController.

But sadly I cant do this with a dynamic Prototype Cell... I just get the error:

> Couldn't compile connections ... >> anchor >> UIButton...

So how can I implement this?

Kind Regards.

Answer (score 2):

Define a manual segue dragging the whole master view onto the detail view, then add a manual target/action to your custom info button and perform the manual segue there. Of course you must set a segue identifier in the storyboard to later reference it in the code, IB will tell you if you forget to.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of connecting and creating segue from individual cells, you can connect all those segues from the View Controller button, lying below your view in your storyboard. In this case, you will have multiple segues and none of them will be individually connected to cells. And when segues are ready, you can use this method for moving on to the next View Controller depending on which cell is tapped from the `tableView`.

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"yourSegue" sender:nil];
```

You just have to check which cell is tapped and then perform the appropriate Segue on tap using the above code and the respective segue identifier. The `prepareForSegue` method will be called immediately after this method is called.

Look out for the yellow button as shown below your View Screen in your storyboard.

[image]

Drag and drop a segue from that button onto the View Controller that you want to connect.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for both answers: I dragged a manual Sague from the MasterViewController to my Target-ViewController. XCode tells me "Popover Segue with no Anchor."
Should I just define a hidden dummy Button in my MasterView or is there any more dressy solution? Kind Regards

Comment: Using dynamic cells, you will not be allowed to anchor a popover. Hence Yes, you can go for the hidden Button logic for that.

Comment: OK it seems to work 'nearly' :D
I created a Hidden-Button as Anchor. The used an delegate to perform the Segue from the ViewController. All three methods button-action / performSegue / prepareSegue are getting fired. But my Target-ViewController does not appear. (The Info-Button is getting grayed so the "layer" seems to show up, but not the View it-self). Kind Regards

Comment: Put a breakpoint on your TargetViewController's `viewDidLoad` method and check whether it is actually going there or stops somewhere in the Source Controller itself.

Comment: That means it is going to the Target View Controller and something is troubling it there. Keep stepping through the `viewDidLoad` method and check further at the point where the execution is stopping. And check the error/crash log if any.

Comment: There are no other calls than `[super viewDidload]`. Do I have to init the ViewController somehow before calling the Segue? If yes, how? I thought the its done automatically...

Comment: Its done implicitly, we dont need to mention it. Is it giving any error or crash log during execution of the TargetViewController ?

Comment: Check the height and width constaints of the destination View. Should not be zero.

Comment: Its a freeform with fixes width and height. Currently holding two static cells.

Comment: I found the problem: The ViewController does appear, but its out of sight. How can I change the position to my dynamic cell? Kind Regards.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58769/discussion-between-icoder-and-mario).